# set has data of one row but i get an exception when i try to retrieve the data

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

The following snippet fetches the name of the photo from the database :

```
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/photog");
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        String sqlQuery = "select nameofthephoto from photocaptions where useremail='" + email + "'";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        set = statement.executeQuery();
        if(set == null) {
            System.out.println("set is null !");
        } else if(set != null) {
            System.out.println("set is not null !");
            System.out.println(set.next());
            System.out.println(set.getString("nameofthephoto")); // last statement
          }
```

**The else-if blocks executes**

The result of the last 2 statements of the code is :

```
false
```

the last statement throws an exception which is

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.

There is only one 'data row' in the table that matches the query which is also visible by the false result shown by `while.next()` . Then why does the last statement (stacktrace says this) in the above snippet throw an exception ?_

Comment: also what is the use of pstmt when you are not setting any param

Comment: @skaffman why did you remove your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Right from the docs,

> When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned
>   after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which
>   requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown.

So that says it all, you have passed the row list hence your next statement to fetch record is throwing error,

next will return false if there are no rows, true if there are rows. So can you check if  in your database you have any row.

Answer (score 0):

set.next() Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position and return true. But in your case theres no data in result set to move the cursor forward. So your desired operation can not be performed.

Comment: _"But in your case theres no data in result set to move the cursor forward."_ how do you say that ?